# Android: In App Purchased list queryInventoryAsync, Google returning wrong purchased list

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I have same account on two different devices. if I purchased something on one device it will not showing on another device. I am using queryInventoryAsync to get the skuList. but google returning different results on both devices.

But if I uninstalled the app and install it again it will  return right result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Play caches In-app Billing information locally on the device from V3 onwards. Instead of getting data from Google server evry time it looks up the local cache when ever you query for the purchase. That might be the reason when you are querying you did not get the correct results. Clear Cache Data of Google Play App and launch your app. This time Google restores the purchase information from Google Server which may gives you the correct results.

Comment: yes, it is working but this is not a feasible solutions .  i have to update purchases every time when i open my app.   is there any doc or something from that i can take reference.

Answer (score 0):

Query to google always returns the purchased items associated with the account. Even you login with the account on multiple devices, It returns you the same purchased list on all devices.

The problem might be you have multiple accounts on a single device.

You purchased the IAP from one account say ***xxx@gmail.com*** in device "**xxx**".
You have another device "**yyy**" where your app is dowloaded from ***yyy@gmail.com***.
You might be adding "***xxx@gmail.com***" on device **yyy**.

in this case your primary account on device "**yyy**" is ***yyy@gmail.com***. query to google retuns purchased items for account ***yyy@gmail.com***.

If the device has more than one account, the purchase/query will be made with the account that downloaded the app

Comment: But I have 2 devices and both have same one primary account, no other account has been  added. When i purchased item from device one and this purchase not reflect from other device.

Comment: The purchase will reflect fro sure. But it may takes some time. Wait and try. Definately you will get. If it is something inconsistent in reflection, you may need to look up.

Comment: Around 3 to 4 hours before i have purchased item but still it is not reflecting

Comment: you said like after an uninstall and reinstall you got right results

Comment: yes, after uninstall the app and download it again i am getting right result.

Comment: m not sure why it's happening like this. But when you query the inventory it must give you the bundle of purchased items. It is not necessary to uninstall and reinstall to get reflected. You can try in another device with the same account.

Comment: One more strange thing happens, when i am restarting  the device and open my app  then it is showing the right in app purchase list. may be the problem with google play service.